# Store category record using JTable instance from controller

Tags: category, jtable

I want to store a category record from controller by using `JTable`. My working code is-

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Category');
$data = array('id' => 0, 'parent_id' = 1, 'path' => 'demo', 'level' => 1, 'title' => 'demo');

if ($table->bind($data)) {
    $table->store(true);
}
```

This code section store the record into `#__categories` table but problem is it stores `parent_id = 0` and `level = 0` always. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you need to bind to the instance? Can you not just add properties to the object like this? https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=592653 can you `var_dump($table)`?  This looks perhaps related https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=554960  or maybe this: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=247046

Comment: @mickmackusa one of your link solves my problem. $table->moveByReference(0, 'last-child', $table->id); is the solution.

Comment: I will invite you to post a complete and educational solution as an answer (then eventually accept your own answer).  I am happy that you discovered the resolution so quickly.  Please share your findings generously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solution by the help of @mickmackusa and using this forum link https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=592653.

My final code is now

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Category');
$data = array('id' => 0, 'parent_id' = 1, 'path' => 'demo', 'level' => 1, 'title' => 'demo');

if ($table->bind($data)) {
    if ($table->store(true)) {
        $table->moveByReference(0, 'last-child', $table->id); // this method generates the original parent_id and level for me.
    }
}
```